# My javascript is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I made a javascript to switch an image on my webpage with onmouseover.
This is working when i use IE google chorome and safari, however when using firefox the script doesnt work i hope you guys can help me out.
-lars

HTML:

```
<table id='bedrijfen_tabel' class='alinea'>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Bedrijf</th><th>Lokatie</th><th>Opgericht</th><th>Website</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id='google' onmouseover="showlogo();"><td>Google</td><td>1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View</td><td>4 september 1998</td><td><a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
        <tr id='facebook' onmouseover="showlogo();"><td>Facebook</td><td>1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park 94025</td><td>4 februari 2004</td><td><a href="www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showlogo(){
    bedrijf = event.currentTarget.id;
    foto = document.getElementById("logo");
    logo.src = "images/" + bedrijf + ".jpg";
    logo.alt = bedrijf;
}
```

Comment: Could you show some more of your code? Could be a dozen of things that is causing the problem.

Comment: so where is `event` defined? if this is a click handler, normally the event object is passed into it as a parameter.

Comment: Should be `function showlogo(event)`?

Comment: where is `logo` declared and is `foto` ever used? Edit: it's probably that `logo` is being associated with the element with the id of `logo` in all but FF.  maybe change those lines to `foto.src = ` and `foto.alt = `

Comment: Event is a very old and non standard Internet Explorer kludge that chrome has adopted for who knows what reason

Comment: It's totally not clear where `logo` defined, if you are trying to change the `src` of the element with the id `logo` `logo.src ` is the way to go (like @JosephMarikle) already stated. There isn't even an element named "logo" in your HTML.

Comment: Passing the event object, with the function fixed it. But why did it work in chrome and IE?

Comment: **Best practice** try avoiding mixing javascript and html and use [addEventListner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead